# swiftUI Xcode can't find image in assets

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, assets

I'm playing around with SwiftUI, I could display an Image from the asset in my Home page but when I try to call it for a model of some french company I can't ...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Company: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var logo: Image
    var city: String
    var endDate: String
    var contact: String
    var contractType: String

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, logo: Image, city: String, endDate: String, contact: String, contractType: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.logo = logo
        self.city = city
        self.endDate = endDate
        self.contact = contact
        self.contractType = contractType
    }
}

struct CardViewcontent: View {
    let companyList = [
        Company(name: "BBC", logo: Image("BBC"), city: "Boulogne", endDate: "00/00/00", contact: "01010101", contractType: "maintenance"),
        Company(name: "Eliote", logo: Image("eliote"), city: "Boulogne", endDate: "00/00/00", contact: "01010101", contractType: "maintenance"),
        Company(name: "Arthur World", logo: Image("AWPG"), city: "Boulogne", endDate: "00/00/00", contact: "01010101", contractType: "ponctuel"),
        Company(name: "AKCB", logo: Image("AKCB"), city: "Paris", endDate: "00/00/00", contact: "01010101", contractType: "pas de contrat")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("List of Companies")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()

            ForEach(companyList, id: \.name) { company in
                CardView(company: company)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let company: Company

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(company.name)")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom)
            Image("\(company.logo)")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding()
            Text("\(company.city)")
            Text("\(company.contractType)")
            Text("\(company.endDate)")
            Text("\(company.contact)")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

The error:

> No image named 'Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<SwiftUI.Image.(unknown context at $1d4ea7490).NamedImageProvider>)' found in asset catalog for /Users/egage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NetoPark-gtrezayhmddlsdgrfbavwkdwplxf/Build/Products/Debug/NetoPark.app

this is my file no error on build and run it just don't display it, ( I already check if their names are the same from the assets and the code.

Comment: you are assigning type `Image` to `Image` Modifier which is not correct instead change `logo` type to `String` instead `Image` in `struct Company` and update in `Company` list array to assign `String` to `logo` property and then assign to `Image` modifier like `Image(company.logo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logo` property of `Company` is of type `Image`. So, when you do `Image("\(company.logo)")`, you are essentially doing `Image("\(Image("BBC"))")`. When `"\(Image("BBC"))"` is enclosed within `""`, it will print the description i.e `Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<SwiftUI.Image.(unknown context at $1d4ea7490).NamedImageProvider>)`.

So, `Image("\(company.logo)")` is converted to `Image("Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<SwiftUI.Image.(unknown context at $1d4ea7490).NamedImageProvider>)")` and no asset of this name is found.

You can solve this in one of the 2 ways -

1 - Change the type of `logo` to `String` and set it to the name of the image.

```
let companyList = [
    Company(..., logo: "BBC", ...),
    ...
]
```

2 - When creating `CardView`, use `company.logo` directly.

```
company.logo
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .padding()
```